# Php Paypal Express checkout: How to pay through server side request

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

Hello I am using Express checkout for my one of project. This is first time i am working with paypal.

I have following code.

```
var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = '<?php echo site_url().'/cart/' ?>create-payment';
    var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = '<?php echo site_url().'/cart/' ?>execute-payment';
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
        intent:'authorize',
        style: {
            size: 'medium', // small | medium | large | responsive
            shape: 'rect', // pill | rect
            tagline: false
        },

        funding: {
            allowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT]
        },
        client: {
            sandbox: '<?php echo $this->config->item('clientId'); ?>',
        },

        payment: function (data, actions) {
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(data) {
                return data.id;
            });

        },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer
        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID:   data.payerID
            }).then(function() {
                alert('payment completes!');
            });

        },
    }, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Now i want to pay through server side api call. I searched a lot but not getting proper documents for it. I don't know how to pay through server side api.

Don't know what is wrong with documents. They are never adding proper information for integration.

Comment: This just looks like the javascript end that triggers their button and mini-browser. You'll need all the heaping pile of PHP code that goes along with handling the return_url data, tokens, and procedures. Here is their developers documentation site: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/

Comment: Oh, and this is the giant PHP SDK for PayPal which makes a lot of things easier (but comes with it, its own lack of good documentation LOL!): https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Comment: @IncredibleHat You are right. They have lack of documentation. i searched a lot but cannot find any proper doc for server side api source.

Comment: The samples on the SDK has the closest to docs (not really though)... this is the one to begin a payment: [CreatePaymentUsingPayPal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php) ... then this is an example of how to capture the return: [ExecutePayment](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/ExecutePayment.php) ....... its a lot different than the old NVP methods, which are not supported anymore (but exist legacy).